# Adobe Flash application is not working on my android tablet

Tags: android, flash

I gone thorough the adobe flash builder video tutorials and did the same thing to create an application for android device, but when i run the application it is showing Sorry dialog box saying that, **The application Test1-debug(process air.Test1.debug) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.** I tried many times but it is not working. Initially i thought no **Adobe-AIR** in my device, but it is there. I am using **Reliance 3G Tab.** I don't why it is not working, if anybody know this please reply me.

One more thing, i downloaded one APK (which is designed with adobe flash or flex) file from http://coenraets.org/blog/2010/05/sample-application-using-flex-and-air-for-android/ and installed on my android device. **When i run that application only blank screen is appearing, but in video they shown, it is working. Why it is happening like this?? Is any problem with my tablet ?? or application ?? or adobe AIR not installed properly on device ??** Like this i am getting too many doubts. **If anybody know about this or anybody working with adobe flash applications for android devices, please reply me.**

Thanks

Comment: what version of air did you setup in your device, it's better to be the last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am sorry for above posted question, because i thought Reliance 3GTab using ARM V7 CPU but its not. Actually for Adobe AIR minimum requirement is ARM V7 CPU, so that my application is not running.

But **I had good reason to post my question**. Why because.........

In my tablet Adobe AIR has been installed by Adobe Flash builder while downloading the application. After launching the application its showing a dialog box with message **your application has stopped unexpectedly**.

I thought Adobe AIR was not properly installed. so I checked installed applications on my tablet, its showing Adobe AIR icon there.

Then I uninstalled Adobe AIR and launched application, now its showing a dialog box with message **no Adobe AIR found**, so i tried to install Adobe AIR from Android Market. Its showing **Your device is not suitable for this product**, then I checked Adobe AIR requirements. Finally i got the answer why my application is not running.

Comment: If there's a problem with the question, please edit it to be correct. Consider users coming along later - it's easier to have an accurate question and succinct answer. That said, thanks for taking the time to explain why it's not possible!